# sorting k sorted lists by their max element

Tags: algorithm, sorting, time-complexity, big-o, mergesort

If I had k sorted singly linked lists and sorted them (mergesort) by each list's largest element (last in the list), what would the big O (running time / time complexity) be? Assuming list 1 ~ k has different size: n_1 ~ n_k. I was thinking O(k * log(MAX(n_1 ~ n_k))) but not sure how or why I came to that line of thinking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that you have O(k) units of memory to store max element of each list, the time to merge sort lists themselves, i.e. without merging their elements, would be O(sum(N<sub>i</sub>) + k*log k).

The first term is there because you need to navigate to the end of each list exactly once; after that you can "tag" the list with its max value, and perform merge sort on tagged lists. The second term comes from sorting k items using merge sort. The fact that the original lists are sorted becomes irrelevant, because you need to traverse the entire list anyway.

If the lists are modifiable, the timing complexity would remain the same even without an additional storage, because you could reverse the lists, sort them, and then reverse them again. Reversing a list takes O(sum(N<sub>i</sub>)), so the time complexity would remain the same.